# How to copy files from a dead Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: files, copy

My Ubuntu 12.04 is not working. Now I tried to copy some important files using live CD. But when I copy some photos a message shows:

> you do not have the permissions to view contents of this file

Answer (score 0):

Start nautilus as root with command `sudo nautilus`

Note: You might not be able to mount other partitions from a `nautilus` running with root permissions

Comment: Its working ......thank you Arun...thankyou verymuch

Comment: Oh ithekke enth :D

Comment: veedu evideya...evide work cheyyunnu

Comment: veed alappuzha. work onnumilla

Comment: student aano.....

Comment: PSC self study.

Comment: njan LDC aayittu alappuzha water transport department il work cheythittundu

Comment: ubuntu engane interested aayi

Comment: Computer Science aanu padichath